# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

I have developed some cucumber tests succesfully passing and testing some urls with chrome. Nevertheless even though the tests succeed webdriver generates following errors when uploading to the pipeline.

```
INFO webdriver: DATA {
57[0-0]   capabilities: {
58[0-0]     alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true },
59[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
60[0-0]   },
61[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true }
62[0-0] }
ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515
64[0-0]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/builds/zdf-cloud/fitness-functions/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:962:111)
65[0-0]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
66[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:323:22)
67[0-0]     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
68[0-0]     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/builds/zdf-cloud/fitness-functions/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:43:20)
69[0-0]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
70[0-0]     at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
71[0-0]     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
72[0-0]     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
73[0-0]     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
74[0-0]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16)
75[0-0] 2022-02-18T10:21:26.227Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
76[0-0] Unable to connect to "http://localhost:9515/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
77[0-0] If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
78[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (/builds/zdf-cloud/fitness-functions/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:72:15)
79[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
80[0-0] FAILED in chrome - /src/cucumber/features/www/originCheck.feature
812022-02-18T10:21:26.343Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
82Spec Files:    0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:11 
832022-02-18T10:21:26.345Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
842022-02-18T10:21:26.596Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
852022-02-18T10:21:26.597Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

I have tried using the configurations recommended in webdriver mainsite https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service/ and variations of these described in other forums with and without all possible combinations of `chromedriver`and `selenium-standalone`implemented in wdio.conf.js:

```
 capabilities: [{
  
        maxInstances: 5,

        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true
    }],
    logLevel: 'info',
    
    baseUrl: '',

    waitforTimeout: 10000,
  
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
   
    services: 
    [
        ['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { firefox: '0.29.1', chrome: true, chromiumedge: 'latest' } }],
    ['chromedriver',
     {
            logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log',
            outputDir: 'driver-logs',
            chromedriverCustomPath: './chromedriver.exe'
    }]
],
```

Nevertheless without success. I have tried downgrading the chromedriver to 98.0.4758.102 version and also using different docker images in pipeline and yet becoming the 'Failed to create session.' issue. Are there any suggestions on how to properly solve this issue and avoid session creation error by using chrome for webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

WDIO V7, selenium standalone: 7.20.3

The issue appears for Microsoft Edge browser if browserName is not correct in capabilities as:
browserName: 'edge'

correct name:

```
browserName: 'microsoftEdge'
```

https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service/